# How to apply background image from Local Drive

Tags: css

How to apply background image from local drive instead of internet. Where is the mistake?

I have tried this way, it is success. (URL from Internet)

```
body.my-login-page {
    background: url(https://hdwallsource.com/img/2014/9/green-gradient-wallpaper-26051-26736-hd-wallpapers.jpg) #277214  no-repeat;
}
```

But this method is unsuccessful. (path from Local)

```
body.my-login-page {
    /* background-color: #6aaaeb; */
    background: url(/images/green_wallpaper.jpg) #277214  no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Where is the image located compared to your css file? You are currently giving a full path to your image rather than a relative path. If your file is in a 'images' folder located at the same level than your css file then you need to write the url as 'images/green_wallpaper.jpg' if the folder is at the same level than your css folder you need './images/green_wallpaper.jpg' for example.

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you use a full file path, or add a "..".

1. Full File Path Example: `C:\Users\Photos\image.png`
2. ".." Example: `../Photos/image.png`

Comment on this post if that does not work, but in the past, that has worked for me.  Also, I would suggest using `<img src="/images/file.png"></img>`, since in my experience it has better compatibility.

Here is a fixed version of your example, using both of the methods I stated:

".." Example:

```
body.my-login-page {
    background: url(../images/green_wallpaper.jpg) #277214  no-repeat;
}
```

Full File Path Example:

```
body.my-login-page {
    background: url(C:/<INSERT PATH>/images/green_wallpaper.jpg) #277214  no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer, just apply as david said above with double dot ".."

```
body.my-login-page {
    background: url(../images/green_wallpaper.jpg) #277214  no-repeat;
}
```